# reCAPTCHA Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, recaptcha, unexpected-token

We use reCAPTCHA ver 2 as checkbox "I am not bot". Since from 2020-11-05 19:23:00Z during our page loading we get exception:

```
recaptcha__ru.js:211 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at recaptcha__ru.js:211
    at recaptcha__ru.js:209
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__ru.js:132)
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__ru.js:208)
    at GM.$ (recaptcha__ru.js:211)
    at Array.<anonymous> (recaptcha__ru.js:253)
    at QS.next (recaptcha__ru.js:416)
    at y (recaptcha__ru.js:355)
```

Exception occurs in https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LcOyt8ZAAAAAD9WJMwwwvgvSGp8Bi0zWYS-FMX5&co=aHR0cDovL2JsYWNrYmlyZDo0ODA4MA..&hl=ru&v=1AZgzF1o3OlP73CVr69UmL65&size=normal&cb=a79dhaz0etu

[image]

Our page has not been changed. The reCAPTCHA breaks unexpectedly in one moment. On other page reCAPTCHA is still working (may be it is important the working page is a embedded inside iframe).

Any hints? What went wrong?

**UPDATED**

We try to isolate reCAPTCHA inside iframe in our JSP page as [@user2384519](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2384519/user2384519)  suggested:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Captcha test</title>
<script>
    function extractRecaptchaResponse() {
        var c = document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-isolator');
        if (c) {
            var src = c.contentWindow.document
                    .getElementById('g-recaptcha-response');
            if (src) {
                var target = document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response');
                target.value = src.value;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h:form id="g-recaptcha-form">

        <h:panelGroup>
            <iframe id="g-recaptcha-isolator" src="/recaptcha.htm"
                onload='javascript:(function(o){o.style.height=o.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+"px";}(this));'
                style="height: 78px; width: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden;">
            </iframe>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"
            style="display: none"></textarea>

        <h:panelGroup>

            <h:commandLink onclick="extractRecaptchaResponse()"
                actionListener="#{recaptcha.submit}">
                <span>Submit</span>
            </h:commandLink>

        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

recaptcha.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxx"></div>
```

and it solves the problem with JSON error, but reCAPTCHA shows popup with image selector and iframe cuts the popup.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**If you are using Prototype.js:**

The Prototype JS library overrides the method `reduce` in the class `Array`.

The issue is resolved if you just add the following script after all imports (preferentially after the body tag):

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function(callback, initialVal) {
    var accumulator = (initialVal === undefined) ? undefined : initialVal;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (accumulator !== undefined)
            accumulator = callback.call(undefined, accumulator, this[i], i, this);
        else
            accumulator = this[i];
    }
    return accumulator;
};
```

Comment: Outstanding, works like a charm.  This fix appears to work in any library that uses prototype.js

Answer (score 3):

We also faced the same issue on 11/5. For quick fix, we have embedded recapcha in iframe. It was getting block by ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js

Comment: I try to isolate recaptcha in iframe, but how do you solve problem with showing image selector inside iframe?     <iframe id="g-recaptcha-container" src="/Template/recaptcha.htm"
     onload='javascript:(function(o){o.style.height=o.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+"px";}(this));'
     style="height: 78px; width: 100%; border: none; overflow: hidden;">
    </iframe> how do you adapt iframe size?

Comment: Try this width: 310px; height: 84px;

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem, then identified that the issue was a conflict caused by another minified js file loaded on the same page.

We trimmed down what js was loaded on the page down to a bare minimum, eliminating the collision, and now it works fine again.

Comment: Thank you for remark. Which collision do you have? How to detect collision?